# Sax parsing best practices

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, sax, saxparser

What are the best ways to minimize the pain of implementing a sax parser to build an object tree?  Like, in what method do you create java objects and where do you store them, how do you keep and use a stack for complex hierarchies, how do you handle attributes, and how do you handle nested elements?  How do you handle character data?

Basically, where does core functionality fit to make life easiest?

Comment: Why do you need to implement a sax parser? There is a large variety of them. What kind of object tree you want to build?

Comment: It sounds to me like he is using SAX to build a limited DOM.

Comment: just using sax to parse xml with a schema, not creating a new parser.

Comment: The answer might be to simply avoid SAX, and use VTD-XML instead.

Comment: I've had recent success with StAX, I recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

I frequently use Dom4j's [SAXReader](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/io/SAXReader.html) with an [ElementHandler](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/ElementHandler.html) to [build mini-DOM chunks of a large XML file](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/faq.html#large-doc).

There are a few things to keep in mind:

1. Call `elementPath.getCurrent()` to get the actual element in your `onEnd()`.
2. Remember to call `element.detach()` at the end of your `onEnd()` method.
3. The path you give to [`addHandler(String, Handler)`](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/io/SAXReader.html#addHandler%28java.lang.String,%20org.dom4j.ElementHandler%29) is NOT an xpath: it's just [a `'/'`-separated Path stack](https://github.com/kaeppler/dom4j-1.6.1-harmony/blob/master/src/java/org/dom4j/io/DispatchHandler.java#L163).

Comment: Forsooth!  The Answer Preview handled my link-reference properly, but the posted answer messed it up!  Editing...